# How can I match and replace an incorrectly spelled string value in a dataframe with the correct spelling in a second dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to replace a large number of incorrectly spelled values in a dataframe with the correct spellings. This is going to be an ongoing process as the dataset will continue to be updated, and therefore needs to be done as efficiently as possible.

Two obvious solutions came to mind at first:

1) dataframe.replace()

2) Merging the dataframe with another using the incorrect values as a key

These options do not seem to be practical solutions to my problem for multiple reasons.

For solution 1 (dataframe.replace()), I simply have too many values that need replaced to keep adding in line after line of df.replace commands every time I ingest new data.

For solution 2 (merge dataframes), I have over a dozen columns that need to be altered, so I would have to create many individual dataframes, some of which would be identical other than the name of the column I would use as a key for the merge.

Below is a simple example of what the two dataframes I would (ideally) be working with would be.

df1:

```
ResponseID      InputA       InputB
-------------------------------------
|ABC123     |   Chikcen   |  First  |
|DEF456     |   Cwo       |  Second |
|GHI789     |   Dog       |  Third  | 
-------------------------------------
```

df2:

```
Old_Value      New_Value
---------------------------
|Chikcen    |   CHICKEN   |
|Cwo        |   COW       |
|Dog        |   DOG       |
|First      |    1        |
|Second     |    2        |
|Third      |    3        |
---------------------------
```

I would like to run those columns in df1 (InputA and InputB) against column Old_Value in df2, and replace those values with the corresponding values in column New_Value.

It would ideally produce the following dataframe

df_final:

```
ResponseID      InputA       InputB
-------------------------------------
|ABC123     |   CHICKEN   |  1      |
|DEF456     |   COW       |  2      |
|GHI789     |   DOG       |  3      | 
-------------------------------------
```

If this is indeed possible, I can't imagine the solution being very complicated. My problem is that I don't know what this type of process would even be named to look for a preexisting answer somewhere.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is one case that `apply` comes in handy:

```
df2.set_index('Old_Value', inplace=True)

df1.iloc[:,1:]  = df1.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x: x.map(df2['New_Value']))
```

Output:

```
  ResponseID   InputA InputB
0     ABC123  CHICKEN      1
1     DEF456      COW      2
2     GHI789      DOG      3
```

Note that `apply` is essentially a for loop on columns, so you don't loose much performance by using it here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` here to map the old value to the new value. Only trick is here that you want multiple columns. So we have to use `apply` here:

```
final = df1.set_index('ResponseID')\
           .apply(lambda x: x.map(df2.set_index('Old_Value')['New_Value']))\
           .reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
  ResponseID   InputA InputB
0     ABC123  CHICKEN      1
1     DEF456      COW      2
2     GHI789      DOG      3
```

Comment: 1. You don't really need `set_index().reset_index()` if all you need is to ignore the first column. 2. applying `set_index()` inside the `lambda` function can also be a little more costly than applying it outside.

Comment: I used `set_index`, so I don't have to use `iloc`. What if the `ID` column is somewhere in the middle?. Second, I don't like to overwrite the dataframe of OP with `inplace=True` since he might want to use it further on. @QuangHoang

Answer (score 0):

use [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
final_df=df1.copy()
final_df['InputA']=final_df['InputA'].map(df2.set_index('Old_Value')['New_Value'])
final_df['InputB']=final_df['InputB'].map(df2.set_index('Old_Value')['New_Value'])
print(final_df)

  ResponseID   InputA InputB
0     ABC123  CHICKEN      1
1     DEF456      COW      2
2     GHI789      DOG      3
```